# Taylor Series expansion of $\frac{(1+x)}{(x-1)^2}$

Tags: taylor-expansion

> Show that the taylor Series expansion of $\frac{(1+x)}{(x-1)^2} = \sum_{n=0} (2n+1) x^n$ valid for $|x| < 1$

Since, $\frac{1}{(x-1)(x-1)} (1+x),$

According to what I learnt, I'm trying to prove this taylor expansion true by using the taylor series expansion of $\frac{1}{1-x} = \sum_{n=0} x^n $

I can only solve it by using this method but I have no clear direction and unsure how to prove it using $\frac{1}{1-x} = \sum_{n=0} x^n $

Comment: "I have tried nothing and I'm all out of ideas" Ok then.  Why don't you think about what you could possibly do with the tools you have available to you, and see what happens when you do it?

Answer (score 1):

The advice is here
$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}
&= \left( \frac{1}{1-x} \right)^2 \\
&= \left( \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n \right)^2 \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^n x^n \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+1) x^n.
\end{align*}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Another explanation could be $${1\over (1-x)^2}={d\over dx}{1\over 1-x}={d\over dx}\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n=\sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^{n-1}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+1)x^n$$